# Configure GremlinServer to JanusGraph with HBase and Elasticsearch

Tags: janusgraph

Can't create instance of GremlinServer with HBase and Elasticsearch.
When i run shell script: bin/gremlin-server.sh config/gremlin.yaml. I get exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.build()

Gremlin-server logs

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/janusgraph/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/janusgraph/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - 
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

135  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Configuring Gremlin Server from config/gremlin.yaml
211  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
557  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseCompatLoader  - Instantiated HBase compatibility layer supporting runtime HBase version 1.2.6: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseCompat1_0
835  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - HBase configuration: setting zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure
836  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Copied host list from root.storage.hostname to hbase.zookeeper.quorum: main.local,data1.local,data2.local
836  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Copied Zookeeper Port from root.storage.port to hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort: 2181
866  [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
1214 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper  - Process identifier=hconnection-0x1e44b638 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=main.local:2181,data1.local:2181,data2.local:2181
1220 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
1220 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:host.name=main.local
1220 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_212
1220 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
1220 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre
1221 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/user/janusgraph/conf/gremlin-server:/home/user/janusgraph/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
// Here hanusgraph download very many dependencies
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.name=Linux
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
1256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.name=user
1257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.home=/home/user
1257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.dir=/home/user/janusgraph
1257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=main.local:2181,data1.local:2181,data2.local:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x1e44b6380x0, quorum=main.local:2181,data1.local:2181,data2.local:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure
1274 [main-SendThread(data2.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server data2.local/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
1394 [main-SendThread(data2.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to data2.local/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, initiating session
1537 [main-SendThread(data2.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session establishment complete on server data2.local/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181, sessionid = 0x26b266353e50014, negotiated timeout = 60000
3996 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.core.util.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader  - Loaded and initialized config classes: 13 OK out of 13 attempts in PT0.631S
4103 [main] INFO  org.reflections.Reflections  - Reflections took 60 ms to scan 2 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
4400 [main] WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Local setting cache.db-cache-time=180000 (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (10000).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
4453 [main] WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Local setting cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20 (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (50).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
4473 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - Closing master protocol: MasterService
4474 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x26b266353e50014
4485 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Session: 0x26b266353e50014 closed
4485 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - EventThread shut down
4500 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8873843641-main-local1
4530 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - HBase configuration: setting zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure
4530 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Copied host list from root.storage.hostname to hbase.zookeeper.quorum: main.local,data1.local,data2.local
4531 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Copied Zookeeper Port from root.storage.port to hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort: 2181
4532 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper  - Process identifier=hconnection-0x5bb3d42d connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=main.local:2181,data1.local:2181,data2.local:2181
4532 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=main.local:2181,data1.local:2181,data2.local:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x5bb3d42d0x0, quorum=main.local:2181,data1.local:2181,data2.local:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure
4534 [main-SendThread(main.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server main.local/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
4534 [main-SendThread(main.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to main.local/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181, initiating session
4611 [main-SendThread(main.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session establishment complete on server main.local/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181, sessionid = 0x36b266353fd0021, negotiated timeout = 60000
4616 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [search]
5781 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 16
6322 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring total store cache size: 186687592
7555 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.IndexSerializer  - Hashing index keys
7925 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog  - Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2019-06-13T09:54:08.929Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@656d10a4
7927 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [config/db.properties].
7927 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.build()
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.initializeGremlinScriptEngineManager(GremlinExecutor.java:522)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.<init>(GremlinExecutor.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.<init>(GremlinExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor$Builder.create(GremlinExecutor.java:813)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:169)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:363)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.build()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.initializeGremlinScriptEngineManager(GremlinExecutor.java:492)
    ... 7 more
```

Graph configuration:

```
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=main.local,data1.local,data2.local
storage.port=2181
storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure

cache.db-cache=true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20
cache.db-cache-time=180000
cache.db-cache-size=0.5

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
index.search.port=9200
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=false

gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
host=0.0.0.0
```

Gremlin-server configuration

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer

graphs: { graph: config/db.properties }

scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: {
               org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: { classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*] },
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: { files: [scripts/janusgraph.groovy] }
    }
  }
}

serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] } }

  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true } }

  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] } }

metrics: {
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000}
}
```

What do I need to do to server start without error?